# Label of y-axis missing in imported plots with pgfplots when compiling wth XeLatex

Tags: pgfplots, xetex, standalone

I use PdfLatex while writing my Latex documents, however I am currently experiencing with XeLatex. While compiling some articles with several plots with XeLatex (and that compiled perfectly with PdfLatex), I noticed that the y-axis label of all pgfplots imported in the main document through either \includegrahics or \includestandalone were missing.

A minimum example is given by the code below:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}

    \usepackage{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
        \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

    \includegraphics{simple-plot.tex}

    \includestandalone{simple-plot}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
            xlabel={x label},
            ylabel={y label},
        ]
        
            \addplot coordinates {(1,1) (2,2)};
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

where the contents of `simple-plot.tex` are:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
        \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
            xlabel={x label},
            ylabel={y label},
        ]
        
            \addplot coordinates {(1,1) (2,2)};
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When compiling the first code with PdfLatex, I get the same plots for the three commands, as expected:

[image: Compiled with pdflatex]

However, when compiling with XeLatex, the first two didn't show the y-axis label, whereas the explicit inclusion of the tikzpicture (third plot) with the axis environment works fine:

[image: Compiled with xelatex]

I know I could always explicitly include the plots in an article document, however I prefer to keep the plots in separate files for better organization.

Does anybody has ever seen this behavior and know how to fix it? I am not sure whether it is a version problem and I couldn't find any solution or comment on it so far.

Thanks!

Comment: I can not reproduce your error. Compile your standalone and look at the result. Update your question with further information.

Comment: @hpekristiansen done. I hope the plots help in understanding the problem.

Comment: Does `simple-plot.pdf` have the y label when made with XeLaTeX? Exactly how do you compile? What version are you using? I can not reproduce the problem with `hpek:~/Temp/tex$ xelatex -version
XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021)
kpathsea version 6.3.3...`

Comment: @hpekristiansen first, thanks for the help! Yes, the `simple-plot.tex` have the y label when run with XeLaTeX. I am using VimTex, and exactly issuing the command `xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -no-pdf -file-line-error -recorder -output-directory=build file.tex`. I am using `XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) kpathsea version 6.2.3`.

Comment: I just tested by running only `xelatex -output-directory=build file.tex', and the same behavior occurs.

Answer (score 0):

For those who eventually have the same issue, based on the comments in the question, it seems to be a problem with version `XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) kpathsea version 6.2.3`.

After updating to Tex Live 2019, the compilation with XeLaTeX works fine.